# How to catch ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE in FirebaseAuth in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to authenticate new users and storing their email and password into FirebaseAuth using the following code:

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
            if user == nil || error != nil {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Please Try Again",
                                              message: "Invalid email or password",
                                              preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) {_ in })
                self.present(alert, animated: true)
            }
            else {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "nextpage", sender: self)
            }
        }
```

However, I'm running into a problem, which is that when a user enters an email is already in use, FirebaseAuth doesn't return an error; instead, it simply overrides the current email. I read in the documentation that an error called ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE can be thrown as part of FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException, how can this be caught? Thanks!

Comment: you can check it in total number of Users you have in Database.

Answer (score 2):

Place this code in the callback handler:

```
if let error = error {
    switch FIRAuthErrorCode(rawValue: error!._code) {
    case .emailAlreadyInUse:
        print("Email already in use")
    default:
        print("Other error")
    }
}
```

Now you can remove the `if user == nil || error != nil` if block.

Also see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Enums/FIRAuthErrorCode for a list of error codes.

Comment: This seems to be a step in the right direction. However, I'm currently getting the error message "error has no member code." My compiler also isn't recognizing the errorCodeEmailAlreadyInUse error. I'm thinking this may be due to some update in the syntax. Any ideas?

Comment: @M.Ying Yup the enum case was renamed and the member is called _code. See the update.

Answer (score 0):

**April 2019**

```
{ (error) in
        switch AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error._code) {
        case .emailAlreadyInUse?:
            print("Email is already in use")
        default:
            print("Other error types.")
        }
    }
```